# Retrieving number of child records of a parent in the most efficient way possible

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

Is there an efficient way of finding out how many of each child record a parent record has without doing a SOQL query on each child object? What I want is something like the information shown in the Related List Quick Links component, that I can access in Apex in a governor-limit-friendly way.

For my use case, it doesn't have to be the exact number - '6+' is fine - I just want to know for each child object whether it's 0, or not 0.

Comment: Have you considered rollup summary fields, or Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries or Rollup Helper apps?

Comment: Hi David. I may have to use them as a last resort but I'm trying to avoid them if I can. The background to this question is that I'm trying to identify contact records that I can delete for GDPR reasons and we have a lot of lookups to the contact object (and new ones are added fairly frequently). Roughly speaking, contacts with no child records are safe to delete automatically; those with child records aren't. 

Using DLRS would be burdensome and also runs the risk of someone adding a new custom object, forgetting to add DLRS and having the contact record deleted while it's still needed.